# Numpy: Solve linear equation system with one unknown + number

Tags: python, numpy, math, equation

I would like to solve a linear equation system in numpy in order to check whether a point lines up with a vector or not.

Given are the following equations for a vector2:

> point[x] = vector1[x] + λ * vector2[x]

> point[y] = vector1[y] + λ * vector2[y]

Numpys **linalg.solve()** offers the option to solve two equations in the form:

> a*x + b*y = c

by defining the parameters **a** and **b** in a *numpy.array()*.

But I can't seem to find a way to deal with equations with one fixed parameter like:

> m*x + b = 0

Am I missing a point or do I have to deal with another solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but isn't that like mx+0y=-b?

Comment: Hi, if you have a vector plus a vector times a scalar, then you get a vector as result. So if lambda is a scalar, then you equation should look like this: 
`vector3[x] = vector1[x] + λ * vector2[x]`

Comment: @Jeremy: I do not think so because in the vector example there is the equation: c = mx + b .. two fixed parameters

Comment: @samusa: I do not really understand where the difference to my stated equation system is? Point[x,y] is indeed a vector. I need to calculate lamda to see whether the point is on the line or not :) If that's what zur reply is explaining then I do not seem to get it and maybe need further explanation.. thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I will give it a try to help with this question.

The [numpy.linagl.solve](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) says:

> Computes the “exact” solution, x, of the well-determined, i.e., full rank, linear matrix equation ax = b.

Note the assumptions made on the matrix!

#### Lambda the same

If your `lambda` for the point[x] and point[y] equation should be the same. Then just concatenate all the vectors.

```
x_new = np.concatenate([x,y])
vec1_new = np.concatenate([vec1_x,vec1_y])
...
```

Assuming that this will overdetermined your system and probably it will. Meaning you have too many equations and only one parameter to determine (well-determined assumption violated). My approach would be to go with least sqare.

The [numpy.linagl.lstsq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) has a least square method too. Where the equation is `y = mx + c` is solved. For your case this is `y` = point[x], `x` = vector2[x] and  `c` = vector1[x].

This is copied from the [numpy.linagl.lstsq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) example:

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([-1, 0.2, 0.9, 2.1])
A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T    # => horizontal stack
m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)[0]
```

#### Lambda different

If the lambdas are different. Stack the vector2[x] and vector2[y] horizontal and you have `[lambda_1, lambda_2]` to find. Probably also more equations then lambds and you will find a least square solution.

#### Note

Keep in mind that even if you construct your system from a staight line and a fixed lambda. You might need a least square approach due to rounding and numeric differences.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! That was exactly what I was looking for :) I'll give it a try tomorrow and keep you updated if it worked the intended way!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your equation  2*x + 4 = 0 with sympy:

```
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import Eq, solve

eq = Eq(2 * x + 4, 0)

print(solve(eq))
```